# Tag synonym: ir->infrared

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

[ir](/questions/tagged/ir)->[infrared](/questions/tagged/infrared).  As far as I know, "IR" is just an abbreviation of "infrared," so making them synonyms seems obvious to me, unless there's some meaning of "ir" I'm missing?

Seen here, before taking it out: [Send over infrared on Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591269/send-over-infrared-on-arduino)

Answer (score 3):

### These should not be combined.

They represent different things. Look at the wikis:

[ir](/questions/tagged/ir):

> The idea behind the LLVM IR is to be "light-weight and low-level while being expressive, typed, and extensible at the same time." This is achieved by being as low-level as possible while it still being possible to map higher level concepts to the IR. The LLVM IR also provides type information, which can be useful for some optimizations.

[infrared](/questions/tagged/infrared) doesn't have a wiki as far as I know. However, they **seem to be different things.** Sure, it is confusing. There's only 57 [ir](/questions/tagged/ir) questions, so it might be worth it to sort through all of those and see if any of them are infrared. Then, the tag [ir](/questions/tagged/ir) should be renamed to "llvm-ir" or something similar. However, **they are *not* the same thing.**

Comment: Actually only 21 of the 57 are about llvm-ir, and they should probably be tagged [llvm-ir] instead of just [ir]. Also, at the time I posted this, only one of the 10 questions was about llvm IR. The tag wiki should really be changed.

Comment: @Kevin I agree.

Comment: I've updated the tag wiki accordingly.